# Include external code into Wordpress Plugin

Tags: javascript, wordpress

i'm using this code for import an external html file in my plugin:

```
<?php
   ...
   function showCalendar() {   
        include 'index.html';
   }
    add_shortcode( 'calendar', 'showCalendar' );
?>
```

but into the html i have some of javascript code  like this:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.11.1.js"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.mycode.js"></script>      
</head>
<body>      
    <div class="box">                       
        <script>
            /*some code*/
        </script>   
    </div>
</body>
```

Wordpress is not executing that part. How can i fix that? thx!

Comment: Use full path for your js in .html file @El0din

Comment: thx! that's work fine!

Comment: I am adding this comment as an answer will you add it as best answer @El0din

Comment: yes, put it like an answer and i will vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use full path for your javascript files in .html file.

Answer (score 0):

In Wordpress you can't include scripts directly in files.

You should include your script using [wp_enqueue_scripts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts), or you can register the scripts and include later when you need it using [wp_register_scripts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/).

Comment: tried but still doesn't work, i just include the full path just like @parth mahida said and works

Comment: @El0din ok, but i reccomend you to use the wordpress functions to include your scripts. It's the correct way.

Comment: @Bellu: Although I totally agree that the recommended way of adding scripts in WordPress is using the enqueue/register functions I don't agree with the statement that in WordPress you can't include scripts directly because you can. Best.